# jQuery title bar height affected by floating div

Tags: jquery, css, struts2

I'm having a very weird jQuery problem.

I have a left nav div with this css:

```
#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

I have a body div with this css:

```
#body {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 1px;    
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */     
}
```

for JQuery i use struts plugin

```
sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Customer Examples"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="-1"
    rownumbers="true"
    editurl="%{editurl}"
    editinline="true"
    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
    onEditInlineSuccessTopics="oneditsuccess"
    viewrecords="true"
```

When I put jQuery grid in the body, its title bar stretches to match the height of the nav div. If I remove the left nav, the grid shows fine.

I've tried everything and googled until I'm blue in my face.

I would greatly appreciate any tips.

---

*Edited to add:*

```
struts grid tag opens into
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.grid.struts2"+jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix+".js");
    var options_gridtable = {};
    var options_gridtable_colmodels = new Array();
    var options_gridtable_colnames = new Array();

    options_gridtable_colmodels_id = {};
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.name = "id";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.jsonmap = "id";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.index = "id";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.formatter = "integer";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.editable = false;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.sortable = false;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.resizable = true;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_id.search = true;
    options_gridtable_colnames.push("ID");
    options_gridtable_colmodels.push(options_gridtable_colmodels_id);

    options_gridtable_colmodels_name = {};
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.name = "name";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.jsonmap = "name";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.index = "name";
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.editable = false;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.sortable = true;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.resizable = true;
    options_gridtable_colmodels_name.search = true;
    options_gridtable_colnames.push("Name");
    options_gridtable_colmodels.push(options_gridtable_colmodels_name);
    options_gridtable.datatype = "json";
    options_gridtable.url = "/moneypulse2app/person/jsontable.action";
    options_gridtable.height = 'auto';
    options_gridtable.pager = "gridtable_pager";
    options_gridtable.pgbuttons = true;
    options_gridtable.pginput = true;
    options_gridtable.rowNum = -1;
    options_gridtable.rowList = [10,15,20];
    options_gridtable.viewrecords = true;
    options_gridtable.editinline = true;
    options_gridtable.caption = "Customer Examples";
    options_gridtable.autoencode = true;
    options_gridtable.rownumbers = true;
    options_gridtable.onselectrowtopics = "rowselect";
    options_gridtable.oneisuccess = "oneditsuccess";

    options_gridtable.colNames = options_gridtable_colnames;
    options_gridtable.colModel = options_gridtable_colmodels;
    options_gridtable.jsonReader = {};
    options_gridtable.jsonReader.root = "gridModel";
    options_gridtable.jsonReader.page = "page";
    options_gridtable.jsonReader.total = "total";
    options_gridtable.jsonReader.records = "records";
    options_gridtable.jsonReader.repeatitems = false;

    options_gridtable.jqueryaction = "grid";
    options_gridtable.id = "gridtable";

    jQuery.struts2_jquery_grid.bind(jQuery('#gridtable'),options_gridtable);

 });
```

It's kinda hard to share it on jsfiddle.net because of all jquery scripts.
May be this HTML part will clarify something:

```
<div style="width: 325px;" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv">
  <div class="ui-jqgrid-hbox">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" aria-labelledby="gbox_gridtable" 
           role="grid" style="width: 325px;" class="ui-jqgrid-htable">
      <thead>
        <tr role="rowheader" class="ui-jqgrid-labels">
          <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader" 
              id="gridtable_rn" style="width: 25px;">
            <div id="jqgh_rn">
              <span style="display:none" class="s-ico">
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="asc"></span>
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="desc"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader" 
              id="gridtable_id" style="width: 143px;">
            <span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" 
                  style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span>
            <div id="jqgh_id" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
              ID
              <span style="display:none" class="s-ico">
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="asc"></span>
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="desc"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader" 
              id="gridtable_name" style="width: 142px;">
            <span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" 
                  style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span>
            <div id="jqgh_name" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
              Name
              <span style="display:none" class="s-ico">
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="asc"></span>
                <span class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" 
                      sort="desc"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, after playing in firebug it seems that changing this css item on grid header somewhat fixes the problem:

```
.ui-helper-clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

if i remove display: block - the caption shrinks to appropriate height but to small width.

Comment: Your Jquery code would help too.

Comment: Please create a small example in jsfiddle.net. It will be much easier to tell what is going on then.

Comment: If you don't float the nav, does the grid still get really big?

Comment: You can improve your own understanding of the problem by trying to reduce your code into a minimal example, that reproduces the behaviour in question. Also proper, readable formatting of the code can be a big leap towards a solution. And it would show your appreciation and respect for the others' efforts trying to help you.

Comment: Have you cleared your float? Whatever is containing the nav make sure to put: `clear: all;` in its stylesheet.

Comment: In addition, try using overflow: hidden. This has a tendency to fix some funky issues that come up while floating elements. Just make sure your content in any explicitly sized(both height & width) elements isn't expanding past the size of the element.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, it would be easier to help if you removed HTML and jQuery code that was not related to the problem. Duplicate the HTML file and delete as much as you can without the problem disappearing. Once you have done this, edit your question and replace the old code with the shorter version.

In lieu of seeing this, have you tried to apply `overflow: visible;` to the block that is growing too big, and see if that resolves the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem with jquery dialog boxes as well - a number of floating divs were causing the title of the dialog to grow in height. Adding overflow: hidden; fixed the problem for me - the title height became constant.